# How can I stop an ‘if’ condition comparing two array items from being met by previously compared items?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I am creating an item recognition quiz with a two-dimensional array of items each comprising a name and image location in the following form:

```
var items = 
[["Item1", "<img src='assets/images/item1.png'  alt='Item1' />"],
["Item2", "<img src='assets/images/item2.png'  alt='Item2' />"],
["Item3", "<img src='assets/images/item3.png'  alt='Item3' />"], etc.]
```

Four items are randomly selected from this array and their names assigned each to a button:

```
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = itemChosen1[0];
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = itemChosen2[0];
document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = itemChosen3[0];
document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = item Chosen4[0];
```

These four items are pushed to another array and one of them is randomly selected as the question image:

```
let imageToUse = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var imageChosen = images[imageToUse]; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = imageChosen[1];
```

A jQuery click function is assigned to each button.  If the name on the button matches the name on the question image then a checkmark is shown and the score incremented:

```
if (itemChosen1[0] == imageChosen[0]) {
      $(".correct1").show();
      document.getElementById("score").innerText++
}
```

Intermittently the score increments by more than one as the ‘if’ condition seems to be met by previous answers.  The previous answers do not show up in the arrays when checked with console.log or browser tools.  Please advise how I can stop this happening.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtzqpf93/) for more info.

Comment: The short answer is to use `else if`, however you can dramatically shorten that code. For one, you seem to know about arrays and how to use them but then turn around and use `ItemChosen1` to `ItemChosen4`, instead of an array again. Also, your list of items contains arrays of strings which can be derived in full from the index. There's absolutely no need to spell out `"<img src=assets/image0.png alt='item0'/>"` ten times when the only thing that ever changes between these strings is the exact number that is the array item's index.

Comment: ok.. testing out ur thing and the double addition happens WHEN you get one wrong, then one correct then ANOTHER ONE CORRECT(then it happens).. sort of like a 011 beat

Comment: I just found the main problem: you keep assigning new click handlers to the buttons each time a new question is displayed, all the previous handlers will still fire when you click. A quick fix is to remove all events from the buttons before assigning a new `click` event handler function: `$('blah').off().on("click", ...)`

Comment: Here's a shorter, fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/07o5zudh/

Comment: @Chris G.  Implemented .attr() on my original code to disable the answer buttons but the score is still incrementing.  Therefore, am incorporating some of your fixed version which seems much more efficient.

Comment: Have now added ('#link').off("click").on("click", ...) and this appears to have fixed my original code.